# How do I take the first 4 bytes of SHA256 in Rust?

Tags: rust, sha

How do I elegantly take first 4 bytes of SHA256 in Rust? Specifically from generic_array produced by:

`sha2::Sha256::new().chain(b"blabla_93794926").result();`

(without using unsafe Rust)

Comment: This could be a lot improved with link and proper [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
let first_bytes = &(Sha256::new().chain(b"blabla_93794926").result()[0..4]);
```

Comment: So basically just create a slice ? I'm sure we have duplicate